# Android Paging 3 - cache data in Repository object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-paging

I am using Paging 3 in Fragments as below (paging data is loaded from network):

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        data.pager.flow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
            postsAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
        }
    }
    postsAdapter.loadStateFlow.asLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        val refresh = it.refresh
        when(refresh) {
            is LoadState.NotLoading -> binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
            is LoadState.Loading -> binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = true
            is LoadState.Error -> {
                binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                showError(getString(R.string.error_loading_posts))
            }
        }
    })
```

Now when I detach and attach same fragment again, the data gets reloaded from network. No cached data is used. I am keeping the PagedData object in Repository object which is app singleton. In Paging 2 I was holding LiveData in Repository and it worked but as now using LiveData in Repository is not recommended I am wondering how can I achieve same behavior.

Comment: You can replace LiveData with StateFlow quite easily. If you were happy with your earlier LiveData code, you can share that and we can help you with the conversion.

Comment: I migrated from Paging 2 to 3 and switched from LiveData to Flow (see my sample code). I just want to know how to cache/use cached data from Paging.